# how to get marker position in jvm map

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am using jvm plugin for map and I have created a labelbox for it. But When I click the marker, it shows labelbox far away. So I need a way to get position of marker (x, y) so the labelbox can be positioned at correct place.
Thanks

Comment: what do you have in your onMarkerClick handler?

Comment: OnMarkClick, I have added a code to display content of infobox..

Comment: I want to get the value of x and y within onMarkClick handler

Comment: it should be `onMarkerClick: function(event, code)` {,,, not `onMarkClick`

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have correctly initialized a map inside a container div called "map", and ypu can get it:

```
var mapObj = $('#map').vectorMap('get','mapObject');
```

I assume you have created your custom "labelbox" outside the map, so you can try to get the position of a marker element as follows:

Inside the onMarkerClick handler use the code of the marker:

```
var style = mapObj.markers[code].element.shape.style.current;
var x = style.cx;
var y = style.cy;
```

Up to you to add some custom logic to keep your custom "labelbox" fully inside the map, if needed.

Comment: This is how I have initialized the map. and onMarkClick handler is also under it:      var map = new jvm.Map({
        container: $('#map'),
        map: 'us_aea_en',
        backgroundColor:'',
        labels: {
          regions: {
            render: function(code){
              
            },
          
          }
        },
        markers: markerss,
         regionStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: '#647680'
      },
      selected: {
        fill: '#647680'
      }
    },
.....